# Is it safe to temporarily store JWT in react native variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt

I'm currently using react-native-secure-storage to store JWTs for my user. The app retrieves data from an Express API so when making an HTTP request I retrieve the token from secure storage and when the async function completes the token is sent it to the API. I've run into a problem now which is that I want to make a component with an image in it served from the API but I can't get the JWT in an async function since the component needs to return immediately. My question is can I just temporarily store the JWT in a variable or in component state?

Comment: yeah you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store it in a variable, in a context, or in a state. I would recommend using React.context() to propapate your JWT token.

Example:

```
const JwtStuffContext =  React.createContext({
    jwt: null,
});

const YourApp = () => {
    const theToken = 'abc';
    return <JwtStuffContext.Provider  value={{ jwt: theToken }}>
        {/** The rest of your app, or {children} */}
    </JwtStuffContext.Provider>
}

const SomewhereDownTheReactTree = () => {
    const { jwt } = useContext(JwtStuffContext);
}
```

Note that if you wanted to avoid sharing the JWT directly with your entire application, you could a function in your state that would proxy your API requests.

However, as you mentioned displaying an image, you could create a special Picture component that fetches the token from  your store, and then requests the image from the API. Like so:

```
const Picture = ({ placeholderSrc, getSrcWithToken }) => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = await yourFunctionToFetchTokenFromstore();
        setToken(token);
    }, [finalSrc]);

    return <img src={token !== null ? getSrcWithToken(token) : placeholderSrc } />;
}
```

The above would display the `placeholderSrc` for as long as the token is unknown, when the token is known, it would call the prop function `getSrcWithToken` passing the token, allowing you to construct the URL if you need to.

Comment: Great thanks, would it be unwise to export that context?